# Creating a read only denormalized datastore from multiple sources

Tags: postgresql, denormalization

I have this common problem within my organization, where we have multiple postgresql schemas, but then we have multiple data heavy list pages that require data from multiple schemas.

For example, one schema will have order information that may contain a city id, but the city information is stored in a different schema.
In many scenarios, the order service can query the city service with the city id or a list of city ids to resolve the name(s), but this doesn't scale well when we want to populate a large data table with paging and allow sorting by city name.

I looked briefly into [postgres fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html), but I'd prefer not to have to create a direct link from one schema to the other.

Is there recommended pattern/practice/tool on combining data from multiple data sources into a single/merged denormalized datastore?

Comment: If by "schema" you really mean schema, but in the same database, then you don't need a foreign data wrapper. You can schema qualify the objects, e.g. `schema.table`...

Comment: I mean schema (postgresql) as in database, potentially on a different server, possibly on the same.